# Custom user model in django to use phone and email both for sign up

Tags: django, model

By default django uses the USERNAME_FIELD  for authentication but it takes only one field. But i want my signup form to let users  sign up by using phone number or by their email, like it happens in facebook . Can anybody help me how can i achieve this ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS

Answer (score 0):

First of all your phone_number field should be unique and you have to create a custom backend for this and register in settings and the backend checks the user by username or phone_number then check the password of the user and if credentials are correct then login user. For example,

```
#backends.py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.models import Q

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserNamePhoneAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """UserName or Phone Authentication Backend.

    Allows user sign in with email or phone then check password is valid
    or not and return user else return none
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username_or_phone=None, password=None, role=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                (Q(username=username_or_phone) | Q(phone_number=username_or_phone)))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

#settings

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "path.for.UserNamePhoneAuthBackend",
)
#views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login
class UserLogin(ApiView):
  def post(self, request):
    username_or_phone = request.data.get("username_or_phone")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    user = authenticate(
            username_or_phone=username_or_phone,
            password=password)
    if user is not None:
     login(user)
    # return token for user
    else:
     return Response("Invalid Credentials")
```